# jQuery dropdown not working any of the browsers

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $("#credit_pay").hide();
  $("#downpayment_method").change(function() {
      if ($("#downpayment_method").val()=='credit_card') {
       $("#credit_pay").show("fast");
      } else { 
       $("#credit_pay").hide("fast");
    };
      if ($("#downpayment_method").val()=='e_check') {
       $("#e_pay").show("fast");
      } else { 
       $("#e_pay").hide("fast");
    };
  });
});
</script>

<tr>
    <td>
        <label for="downpayment_method">Downpayment Method</label>
        <select id="downpayment_method" name="downpayment_method" >
            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
            <option value="credit_card">Credit Card</option>
            <option value="e_check">E-check</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The above code i wrote works great on http://jsfiddle.net/gDtFS/ :
But it does not work in my server.
In firefug it shows the following in red:

$

DP_jQuery_1328833882393

jQuery

I cannot comprehend what the above means.
I have included the following files:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Is there anything I am missing?

```
<div id="credit_pay">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="name_on_card">Name on Card</label>
            <input type="text" name="name_on_card">
            <label for="billing_zip">Billing Zip</label>
            <input type="text" name="billing_zip">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="card_type">Card Type</label>
            <select id="card_type" name="card_type">
                <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                <option value="Visa">Visa</option>
                <option value="Mastercard">Mastercard</option>
                <option value="Discover">Discover</option>
                <option value="Amex">Amex</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>           
</div>
<div id="e_pay">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="name_on_account">Name on Account</label>
            <input type="text" name="name_on_account">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="routing_no">Routing #</label>
            <input type="text" name="routing_no">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="account_no">Account #</label>
            <input type="text" name="account_no">
        </td>
    </tr>

</div>
```

Here is a live link

[cs.txstate.edu/~sr1388/Test](http://cs.txstate.edu/~sr1388/Test)

Comment: the fiddle works fine for me, can you explain what you are seeing a little clearer, what do you mean doesn't work in browser? there must be some other code in your page? maybe you cant connect to the cdn in your network?

Comment: Works in IE8 and Chrome for me?

Comment: What do you mean "does not work on any of my browsers"? Aren't you testing your jsfiddle in one of your browsers? Do you mean it doesn't work when deployed on your web server? I can see some ways your code could be improved, but I don't see anything that would stop it working.

Comment: You do have your tr tags within div tags instead of a table tag in your example but I think you are going to have to elaborate on your problem.

Comment: I tested the markup, script, and jquery include in a sample page and it works for me. My guess would be that there is more in the page that is having the problem then what you have posted here. A quick search for `DP_jQuery` pulls up items relating to date picker. Do you have a date picker in the page that exists on your server? Are you able to provide a link to your live content for people to evaluate?

Comment: ok here is the site:http://cs.txstate.edu/~sr1388/Test/

I tried removing the datepicker and run it but that didn' work either!

Comment: ok there is a error in the firebug saying $ not defined.

Comment: [Your site](http://cs.txstate.edu/~sr1388/Test) is working fine in Safari without errors.  I don't really understand the question.

Comment: @Sparky,yes its working now..thats exactly what I was trying tell.i fixed it to work, but I dont understand why they closed this post!

Comment: "Too Localized" means that it will never help any future readers.  This is not the place to discuss that though... use the Meta site to talk about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Craig it was the `<tr>` tag that was creating the problem
I removed the tables and just used  css. 
Here is the updated link.

Comment: Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information.

Comment: I believe this post would be very helpful for Somoza who is a beginner like me. Never include a <div> tag between a table tag like i did above. Your jquery is unlikely to work.